# php version difference

Tags: php

Any difference between php 5.3.0 and 5.2.15?

I am using 5.3.0 on my localhost and 5.2.15 on the remote server

My apps work well on the localhost and breaks on the remote server.

One particular error is "Only variable should be passed by reference"

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to [the php5 changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php). (I don't see those specific versions listed though. :/)

**Edit**: Ah, no. PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.2 are distinct branches. You will have to compare all the changelog entries for each branch from their original branch point to obtain a list of differences.

Answer (score 1):

This error generally occurs when you pass function return as argument to a function. PHP 5.3 passes each argument as reference whether it is a actual variable or a return from function. This feature was first implemented with PHP 5.3 and not available in PHP 5.2. So, my recommendation would be to step down your development environment to PHP 5.2, so that you can see these errors.

Comment: Is 5.3 not supposed to be more advanced and more stable?